# How can I combine 2 dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, yfinance

I have trying to merge the 20 days rolling mean daataframe witht he 7 days rolling mean dataframe. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

start=dt.datetime.today()-dt.timedelta(90)
end=dt.datetime.today()
cl_price=pd.DataFrame(yf.download("MSFT AAPL FB GOOG AMZN IBM", start=start, end=end)['Adj Close'])
cl_price1=cl_price.dropna()

dailyretrun=cl_price.pct_change()

rolling20=dailyretrun.rolling(window=20).mean()
rolling7=dailyretrun.rolling(window=7).mean()
df=rolling20.join(rolling7)
```

I tried `pd.merge` and `join` but I am getting the below error.

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(
['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'GOOG', 'IBM', 'MSFT'], dtype='objec
t')
```

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney this is so good.. This is pretty much what I am trying to do.thanks a million mate

Comment: I'm glad the duplicated solved the issue. Please also upvote on the quality/helpfulness of that answer, with the up arrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the two dataframes have columns with same name

To join the dataframes use lsuffix and rsuffix in the following way

```
df=rolling20.join(rolling7,lsuffix='_ls', rsuffix='_rs')
```